# how can I hot deploy my project built with play! framework?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Our backend is based on play! framework, so far so good except that we have to shutdown the server every time deploying new build which is very annoying.
Is there a solution to hot deploy play! projects?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you redeploying a Live system? If so, then you might be doing a redeploy a bit too frequently for it to become annoying. A Play! application running locally will pick up changes you make to the code while it's running..

Comment: Every several days we want to release bug fixes/new features. What we want is that no need to shutdown the service to make these changes available to our users.